# Pass arguments to auth_request module from nginx

Tags: php, authentication, nginx, auth-request

I want to protext a live HLS stream. I want to use the auth_request module. I want to check if a request is valid by passing a key. So something like: http://domain.com/hls/stream.m3u8?key=xxxxxxx

I have the following setup in nginx.conf:

```
location /hls {
  alias /tmp/hls;
  auth_request /hls/auth;
}

location /hls/auth {
  proxy_pass http://localhost.com:8080/on_play.php;
  proxy_pass_request_body off;
  proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
  proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
}
```

Now I need to get the key=xxxxx available in http://localhost.com:8080/on_play.php.

I tried a lot but nothing seems to work. I also tried something like:

```
location /hls {
  alias /tmp/hls;
  auth_request http://localhost.com:8080/on_play.php?key=$arg_key;
}
```

But this also doesn't work. There seems not to be a possibility as of to get the key argument in the on_play.php

The $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] also doesn't contain the args.

Also tried following config:

I also tried something like this, but this also doesn't work:

```
location ~ ^/hls/(long|short)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)\.m3u8 {
  alias /tmp/hls/$1/$2.m3u8;
  auth_request /hls/auth-play/$1/$2;
}

location ~ ^/hls/auth-play/(long|short)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) {
  proxy_pass http://loclahost.com:8080/on_play.php?app=$1&room=$2;
  proxy_pass_request_body off;
  proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
  proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
}
```

But this also doesn't work.

The output of nginx -V is:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.6.0
built by gcc 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC)
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-file-aio --with-ipv6 --with-http_spdy_module --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic'
```

I can read the $_SERVER["HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URI"] in php, but I like to have the vars just as $_GET. This doesn't seem to work.

As you can see from the logs below, only the $is_args variable is added in the subrequest. The debug.log is below:

```
2014/06/27 08:41:59 [debug] 27994#0: timer delta: 0
2014/06/27 08:41:59 [debug] 27994#0: posted events 0000000000000000
2014/06/27 08:41:59 [debug] 27994#0: worker cycle
2014/06/27 08:41:59 [debug] 27994#0: epoll timer: 59029
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: epoll: fd:6 ev:0001 d:00000000017C7450
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: accept on IP:80, ready: 0
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: posix_memalign: 00000000017BB920:256 @16
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 accept: IP fd:3
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: posix_memalign: 00000000017BBA80:256 @16
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 event timer add: 3: 60000:1403851380198
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 reusable connection: 1
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 epoll add event: fd:3 op:1 ev:80002001
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: timer delta: 319
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: posted events 0000000000000000
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: worker cycle
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: epoll timer: 58710
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: epoll: fd:3 ev:0001 d:00000000017C7961
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http wait request handler
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 malloc: 00000000017972F0:1024
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 recv: fd:3 390 of 1024
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 reusable connection: 0
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 posix_memalign: 00000000018354C0:4096 @16
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http process request line
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http request line: "GET /hls/group/rsdrsd.m3u8?user=rsdrsd2 HTTP/1.1"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http uri: "/hls/group/rsdrsd.m3u8"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http args: "user=rsdrsd2"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http exten: "m3u8"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 posix_memalign: 00000000018364D0:4096 @16
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http process request header line
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http header: "Host: domain.com"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http header: "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http header: "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http header: "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http header: "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http header: "Cookie: PHPSESSID=c3m0rkb9il0udfgoh9qt91jao0"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http header: "Connection: keep-alive"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http header: "Cache-Control: max-age=0"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http header done
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 event timer del: 3: 1403851380198
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 generic phase: 0
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 rewrite phase: 1
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 test location: "/hls/auth-update"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 test location: "/hls/public"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 test location: ~ "[^/]\.php(/|$)"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 test location: ~ "^/hls/(private|group)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)\.m3u8"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 using configuration "^/hls/(private|group)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)\.m3u8"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http cl:-1 max:1048576
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 rewrite phase: 3
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 post rewrite phase: 4
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 generic phase: 5
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 generic phase: 6
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 generic phase: 7
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 access phase: 8
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 access phase: 9
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 access phase: 10
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 auth request handler
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http subrequest "/hls/auth-play?"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http posted request: "/hls/auth-play?"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 rewrite phase: 1
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 test location: "/hls/auth-update"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 test location: "/hls/auth-play"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 test location: ~ "[^/]\.php(/|$)"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 test location: ~ "^/hls/(private|group)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)\.m3u8"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 test location: ~ "^/hls/(private|group)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)\-([0-9]+)\.ts"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 test location: ~ "^/chat/(?<node>(3000))"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 using configuration "/hls/auth-play"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http cl:-1 max:1048576
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 rewrite phase: 3
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 post rewrite phase: 4
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 generic phase: 5
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 generic phase: 6
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 generic phase: 7
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 posix_memalign: 00000000018374E0:4096 @16
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http script copy: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/on_play.php"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http script var: ""
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http init upstream, client timer: 0
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 epoll add event: fd:3 op:3 ev:80002005
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http script copy: "X-Original-URI: "
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http script var: "/hls/group/rsdrsd.m3u8?user=rsdrsd2"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http script copy: "^M
"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http script copy: "Host: "
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http script var: "127.0.0.1:8080"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http script copy: "^M
"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http script copy: "Connection: close^M
"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http proxy header: "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http proxy header: "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http proxy header: "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http proxy header: "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http proxy header: "Cookie: PHPSESSID=c3m0rkb9il0udfgoh9qt91jao0"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http proxy header: "Cache-Control: max-age=0"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http proxy header:
"GET /on_play.php HTTP/1.0^M
X-Original-URI: /hls/group/rsdrsd.m3u8?user=rsdrsd2^M
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080^M
Connection: close^M
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0^M
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8^M
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5^M
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate^M
Cookie: PHPSESSID=c3m0rkb9il0udfgoh9qt91jao0^M
Cache-Control: max-age=0^M
^M
"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http cleanup add: 0000000001837A58
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 get rr peer, try: 1
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 socket 10
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 epoll add connection: fd:10 ev:80002005
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 connect to 127.0.0.1:8080, fd:10 #40
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http upstream connect: -2
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 posix_memalign: 0000000001789700:128 @16
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 event timer add: 10: 60000:1403851380199
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http finalize request: -4, "/hls/auth-play?" a:1, c:3
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http request count:3 blk:0
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: timer delta: 1
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: posted events 0000000000000000
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: worker cycle
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: epoll timer: 58709
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: epoll: fd:3 ev:0004 d:00000000017C7961
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http run request: "/hls/auth-play?"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http upstream check client, write event:1, "/hls/auth-play"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http upstream recv(): -1 (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: epoll: fd:10 ev:0004 d:00000000017C7A39
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http upstream request: "/hls/auth-play?"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http upstream send request handler
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http upstream send request
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 chain writer buf fl:1 s:419
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 chain writer in: 00000000018374C0
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 writev: 419
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 chain writer out: 0000000000000000
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 event timer del: 10: 1403851380199
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 event timer add: 10: 60000:1403851380199
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: timer delta: 0
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: posted events 0000000000000000
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: worker cycle
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: epoll timer: 58709
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: epoll: fd:10 ev:0005 d:00000000017C7A39
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http upstream request: "/hls/auth-play?"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http upstream process header
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 malloc: 00000000018384F0:4096
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 recv: fd:10 154 of 4096
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http proxy status 403 "403 Forbidden"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http proxy header: "Server: nginx/1.6.0"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http proxy header: "Date: Fri, 27 Jun 2014 06:42:00 GMT"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http proxy header: "Content-Type: text/html"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http proxy header: "Connection: close"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http proxy header: "X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.10"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http proxy header done
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 finalize http upstream request: 0
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 finalize http proxy request
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 free rr peer 1 0
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 close http upstream connection: 10
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 free: 0000000001789700, unused: 48
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 event timer del: 10: 1403851380199
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 reusable connection: 0
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http finalize request: 0, "/hls/auth-play?" a:1, c:2
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 auth request done s:403
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http wake parent request: "/hls/group/rsdrsd.m3u8?user=rsdrsd2"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http posted request: "/hls/group/rsdrsd.m3u8?user=rsdrsd2"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 access phase: 10
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 auth request handler
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 auth request set variables
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http finalize request: 403, "/hls/group/rsdrsd.m3u8?user=rsdrsd2" a:1, c:1
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http special response: 403, "/hls/group/rsdrsd.m3u8?user=rsdrsd2"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http set discard body
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden^M
Server: nginx/1.6.0^M
Date: Fri, 27 Jun 2014 06:42:00 GMT^M
Content-Type: text/html^M
Content-Length: 168^M
Connection: keep-alive^M

2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 write new buf t:1 f:0 0000000001837DC8, pos 0000000001837DC8, size: 154 file: 0, size: 0
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http write filter: l:0 f:0 s:154
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http output filter "/hls/group/rsdrsd.m3u8?user=rsdrsd2"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http copy filter: "/hls/group/rsdrsd.m3u8?user=rsdrsd2"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http postpone filter "/hls/group/rsdrsd.m3u8?user=rsdrsd2" 0000000001837F98
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 write old buf t:1 f:0 0000000001837DC8, pos 0000000001837DC8, size: 154 file: 0, size: 0
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 write new buf t:0 f:0 0000000000000000, pos 00000000006CD6E0, size: 116 file: 0, size: 0
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 write new buf t:0 f:0 0000000000000000, pos 00000000006CD0C0, size: 52 file: 0, size: 0
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http write filter: l:1 f:0 s:322
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http write filter limit 0
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 writev: 322
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http write filter 0000000000000000
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http copy filter: 0 "/hls/group/rsdrsd.m3u8?user=rsdrsd2"
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http finalize request: 0, "/hls/group/rsdrsd.m3u8?user=rsdrsd2" a:1, c:1
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 set http keepalive handler
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http close request
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http log handler
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 free: 00000000018384F0
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 free: 00000000018354C0, unused: 8
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 free: 00000000018364D0, unused: 0
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 free: 00000000018374E0, unused: 1069
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 free: 00000000017972F0
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 hc free: 0000000000000000 0
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 hc busy: 0000000000000000 0
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 tcp_nodelay
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 reusable connection: 1
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 event timer add: 3: 3000:1403851323212
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 post event 00000000017FD6D0
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: timer delta: 13
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: posted events 00000000017FD6D0
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: posted event 00000000017FD6D0
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 delete posted event 00000000017FD6D0
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http keepalive handler
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 malloc: 00000000017972F0:1024
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 recv: fd:3 -1 of 1024
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 recv() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: *39 free: 00000000017972F0
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: posted event 0000000000000000
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: worker cycle
2014/06/27 08:42:00 [debug] 27994#0: epoll timer: 3000
2014/06/27 08:42:03 [debug] 27994#0: timer delta: 3003
2014/06/27 08:42:03 [debug] 27994#0: *39 event timer del: 3: 1403851323212
2014/06/27 08:42:03 [debug] 27994#0: *39 http keepalive handler
2014/06/27 08:42:03 [debug] 27994#0: *39 close http connection: 3
2014/06/27 08:42:03 [debug] 27994#0: *39 reusable connection: 0
2014/06/27 08:42:03 [debug] 27994#0: *39 free: 0000000000000000
2014/06/27 08:42:03 [debug] 27994#0: *39 free: 00000000017BB920, unused: 0
2014/06/27 08:42:03 [debug] 27994#0: *39 free: 00000000017BBA80, unused: 120
2014/06/27 08:42:03 [debug] 27994#0: posted events 0000000000000000
2014/06/27 08:42:03 [debug] 27994#0: worker cycle
2014/06/27 08:42:03 [debug] 27994#0: epoll timer: 55693
```

Comment: proxy_pass http://localhost.com:8080/on_play.php$is_args$args;

Comment: Already tried that one, but that also doesn't work. The args don't get passed to location /hls/auth

Comment: can you please provide the logs with debug level? And the output of *nginx -V* as well.

Comment: Added debug.log and nginx -V. The debug.log is for: proxy_pass localhost.com:8080/on_play.php$is_args$args;

Comment: This is driving me nuts.  Any luck on this?

Comment: Well didn't solve it. Just did it in a different way, by adding the key in the filename.

Answer (score 5):

Got something similar to work like this:

```
location ~ ^/something/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(.*)$ {
    set $auth_request_uri "http://127.0.0.1/api/something/$1/access/$2";
    auth_request /auth;

    alias $SOMEPATH/public/files/$2/$3;
}

location /auth {
    internal;
    proxy_pass $auth_request_uri;
    proxy_pass_request_body off;
    proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
    proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
}
```

Comment: This works for me, but it worries me because I'm not really sure how nginx variables work.

It looks like $auth_request_uri is effectively being used as a global variable. In this case, could one client request set the variable, then authorise a separate client request ? (A race condition)

Comment: @ddouglascarr I would have thought the vars is contained in each request.